# Specify character literal for date and time type in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

In the book, Ben-Gan, Itzik. T-SQL Fundamentals, there is the following statement.

> formats ‘YYYY-MM-DD’ and ‘YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm...’ are language dependent
>   when converted to DATETIME or SMALLDATETIME and language neutral when
>   converted to DATE, DATETIME2, and DATETIMEOFFSET.

I understand that when specifying date and time literal, sql server can interpret the same literal differently according to the language setting.

However, I was unable to clearly understand the above statement. What does it actually mean?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302732/sql-server-why-are-dates-in-iso-8601-format-language-dependent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21302933/192221): The new datatypes in SQL Server 2008 datetime2 and date are not dependent on SET LANGUAGE or SET DATEFORMAT.

Some european locales have 'YYYY-DD-MM', but datetime2 and date always use 'YYYY-MM-DD'. See [connect article](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/290971/deprecate-the-date-literal-interpretation-yyyy-dd-mm-except-in-compatibility-modes-90).

E.g:

```
Set dateformat dmy;
Select cast ('2012-02-01' as datetime) [DateTime], cast ('2012-02-01' as datetime2) [DateTime2],
cast ('2012-02-01' as date) [Date];
```

Results in:

```
DateTime                DateTime2                   Date
2012-01-02 00:00:00.000 2012-02-01 00:00:00.0000000 2012-02-01
```