# SUM/COUNT of similar date

Tags: sql

```
id      Category     userid   Date       Avg
8       Category1       20  18-07-2014  40.0000
8       Category1       16  18-07-2014  60.0000
8       Category1       17  18-07-2014  50.0000
8       Category1       19  18-07-2014  50.0000
8       Category1       18  18-07-2014  60.0000
8       Category1       14  18-07-2014  60.0000
8       Category1       13  18-07-2014  40.0000
8       Category1       15  18-07-2014  60.0000
8       Category1       40  10-10-2014  40.0000
8       Category1       12  26-07-2014  70.0000
8       Category1       51  26-07-2014  40.0000
8       Category1       26  26-07-2014  40.0000
8       Category1       47  26-07-2014  50.0000
8       Category1       48  26-07-2014  50.0000
8       Category1       27  26-07-2014  60.0000
8       Category1       46  26-07-2014  50.0000
8       Category1       21  26-07-2014  60.0000
8       Category1       22  26-07-2014  40.0000
8       Category1       23  26-07-2014  50.0000
8       Category1       54  26-07-2014  40.0000
8       Category1       24  26-07-2014  40.0000
8       Category1       25  26-07-2014  40.0000
8       Category1       60  31-07-2014  40.0000
8       Category1       59  31-07-2014  50.0000
8       Category1       30  31-07-2014  40.0000
8       Category1       55  20-11-2014  70.0000
8       Category1       33  20-11-2014  70.0000
8       Category1       38  20-11-2014  70.0000
8       Category2       24  08-11-2014  70.0000
```

I want to retrieve the count of users between the dates '01-01-2005' AND '21-08-2015'. I tried with the query, but the date field wasn't 
counting the duplicate dates. I need all the users between these dates '01-01-2005' AND 21-08-2015 perfectly as because different users may or maynot 
have same date.

```
SELECT id
      ,category
      ,SUM(Avg) 
WHERE 
FROM_UNIXTIME(Date,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '01-01-2005' AND '21-08-2015'  
GROUP BY id, category.
```

Comment: Not the best date format to use...The ISO fomat would be better YYYYMMDD http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565320/why-is-sql-server-misinterpreting-this-iso-8601-format-date

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (FROM _UNIXTIME is not ANSI SQL...)

Comment: Your question needs a lot of tidying up and clarification.  Which flavour of SQL?  What's the table structure?  I can't believe your supplied query will execute as is.

Comment: Iam using sql server

Comment: Could anyone suggest to get all the dates  including duplicate dates

Comment: I don't understand why my question has got down voting. I had clearly mentioned the question

Answer (score 0):

I've suggested in the comments that your question needs tidying up - I don't think anyone can answer it authoratively as it is.

If I were to speculate - you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(1)       -- The number of records returned
FROM table_name  -- The table you're SELECTing from
WHERE
  `Date` BETWEEN '01-01-2005' AND '21-08-2015'
;
```

But that assumes a lot about the table schema etc - and the flavour of SQL.

Comment: Wally, I guess we can't add count(1)  here as because I was taking SUM

Comment: The query in my answer wasn't showing duplicate dates, that is the only issue.

Comment: Group By?  To aggregate by date you mean?

Comment: Yes wally, I just want the rows even for the duplicated dates

Comment: Now for users 12 to 25, they all scored avg on the same date. I want all the users under that date, which my query isn't counting properly and I observed that it is taking as only one count of user on that date