# How do i convert this date string to datetime?

Tags: sql-server

I have included in the "in" statement the data contained within logdate.

for some reason I can't convert them. I'm more used to oracle databases which handles this stuff more in a forgiving way. So I'm struggling to figure out what is going wrong.

```
  select CONVERT(DATETIME,opencall.logdate,102)
  from opencall
  where logdate in
  (  '17/08/2016 10:33:08'
    ,'17/08/2016 10:33:13'
    ,'17/08/2016 10:33:17'
    ,'17/08/2016 10:34:03'
    ,'17/08/2016 10:34:14'
    ,'17/08/2016 10:34:46')
    ;
```

I get the error 
[S0003][242] The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

and i tried

```
    select cast(opencall.logdate as datetime)
    from opencall
    (
    '17/08/2016 10:33:08'
   ,'17/08/2016 10:33:13'
   ,'17/08/2016 10:33:17'
   ,'17/08/2016 10:34:03'
   ,'17/08/2016 10:34:14'
   ,'17/08/2016 10:34:46'
   )
```

I get error
[S0003][242] The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

What am i doing wrong this time?

:-)

Comment: Your server accepts `MM/DD/YYYY` format so `17/08/2016` consider `17` as month, `08` as date, so it throws the erroe

Comment: the out of range happens because of the DD/MM format so SQL is reading it as the month 17 which doesn't exists.

Comment: Additionally, Sql Server treats datetime values without the full time component as if the remaining part of the time component are all zero. This query will only work if the `opencall` tables have values that **exactly** match `17/08/2016 10:33:08.000`, `17/08/2016 10:33:13.000`, `17/08/2016 10:33:17.000`, etc. Any fractional second values stored in the table _WILL_ break this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting error is that your system is set to mm/dd/yyyy and you are trying to make it accept dd/mm/yyyy, hence any value with dd over 12 or mm over the corresponding number of days of the month will throw an error.

To overcome this use `CONVERT` twice to define the format explicitly.

The first `CONVERT` takes care of the out-of-range issue by specifying that the input is in the format of 103 (European).  The second `CONVERT` cast the result to 102, the US mm/dd/yyyy + time format.

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(datetime, '17/08/2016 10:33:08',103) ,102)
```

Comment: BINGO!!!! 
Thanks man! only two weeks flying time logged on this sql server stuff! and it all started to look so so similar! cruse my arrogance!

Comment: Sure, when it comes to date format it can get tricky since it involves SQL default, OS default, and ODBC setting too.  too many numbers!  cheers mate. (though it's funny someone seems to have down-voted my answer...)

Comment: Alternatively you can simply use SET DATEFORMAT dmy; And CAST

Comment: There is no need to do a double convert and to use an US format, there is a format that is now by any database no matter how your database is setup. It is the ISO standard. Although this answer will work now, it will fail if you where to install this database on a server in a different region (europe for example). Using the ISO standard will ensure that the solution will always work in any circumstance.

Comment: @GuidoG i completely agree.  Everyone and everything should use the standardized format and half the problems will go away.

Answer (score 0):

the safest way is to use the ISO format to format your datetime, it will always be accepted no matter what culture your db is in.

good info can be find here : http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

for having date and time this is your format :  '1998-02-23T14:23:05'

```
select cast(opencall.logdate as datetime)
from opencall
where logdate in
(
  '2016-08-17T10:33:08',
  and so on...
```

Comment: It kinda sucks, but my understanding is there are some edge cases around for historical reasons such that the ISO unseparated format (YYYYMMDD) is better than straight ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD). Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565320/why-is-sql-server-misinterpreting-this-iso-8601-format-date ( read the answer, not the question)

Comment: yes datetimes are a pain in the ... I agree but if you use ISO formats you will never encounter any problems

Comment: cheers chaps! If I had a choice about what the format would be for the database I would. Alas I'm Technical Analyst setting up reporting off the back of a 3rd party application. 

So I get no choice in what format things should be.

Comment: @TuckRollworthy The database keeps a date as a decimal value, the first part is for date the decimal part is for the time. There is no format to choose here. How it displays them and the format it accepts as input can be configured. Its the latter where your problem is. So if you build your query you have a choice, either you figure out the format the database accepts now and build your query like that, or you build it using a standard format that will always work. In the first choice your query will suddenly stop working when settings are changed. But it is your choice offcourse.

Comment: @GuidoG cheers boss! Sorry about the late reply... I've been holidaying!