# Convert function is not working with {fn } in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a development SQL Server, "Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458)"

If I use the `convert` function with `{fn}` then it's working, as expected:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, {fn CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()})
```

[image]

Now, the production database is on "Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB5021125)"

[image]

Translating the error:

> When converting from a varchar data type to a datetime data type, the value is out of range.

Is this a patch bug, and is there a way to check the definition of the convert function in the SQL Server?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also, the problem is likely due to `de-DE`'s regional date/time format being different to your local server. You must always specify the `style` parameter with `CONVERT` when performing date/time string/value conversions.

Comment: I just remembered that `{fn CURRENT_TIMESTAMP}` [is ODBC Syntax which is kinda irrelevant today](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/odbc-scalar-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). Why are you still using it?

Comment: It invokes an ODBC command, @Dai . In this case, it returns a `varchar` with a datetime in the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.nnn` which for anyone that *isn't* American is ambiguous for a `datetime`.

Comment: @ThomA `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.nnn` is ISO 8601-safe and is unambiguous. I think you're thinking of RoW's `dd/MM/yyyy` vs en-US's `MM/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: *"is ISO 8601-safe and is unambiguous."* @Dai that doesn't make it unambiguous in SQL Server. for `(small)datetime` it is **not** unambiguous. `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.nnn` *is* unambiguous for the "*new*" date and time data types (such as `datetime2`), but not the "old" date and time data types.

Comment: @ThomA Ah, [I just found this...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565320/why-is-sql-server-misinterpreting-this-iso-8601-format-date) - so `datetime` (but not `datetime2`) is even worse than I thought - thanks

Comment: Wouldn't the obvious answer be to just do `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of that? It already returns a `DATETIME` when you just call the builtin function without any of the ODBC stuff

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZzGwzQTD) for your reference, @Dai

Comment: If this is existing code that you are looking at and you are trying to understand the reason for the difference in behaviour it will be because the default language of the login is different in both environments BTW

Comment: Aside... `{fn CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()}` is not the same thing as SQL Server's `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. The former is an ODBC scalar function that returns a `timestamp` value, the latter is an SQL Server function that returns a `datetime` value. Because you're wrapping the ODBC function in `{fn ...}` it's actually returning a `varchar(30)` value and so `CONVERT(...)` will be sensitive to the current `SET DATEFORMAT DMY|MDY|YMD` setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, it's not a bug.** Your production server is set to a different language, or the `DATEFORMAT` setting is different.

You need to use an explicit [conversion style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles) to get the right results, 121 is the one you are looking for.

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, {fn CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()}, 121);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sn4JV2mM)

But you might as well use the normal syntax and get a `datetime` result in the first place.

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
```